# why my rule freezed the CLIPSIDE,but each single one loads fine

Tags: clips

```
(defrule rule1
(not
    (or
        (and
            (or
                (Cloud1 (cloudcount FEW|SCT) )
                (Cloud2 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
                (Cloud3 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
                (Cloud4 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
            )
            (or
                (Trend1Cloud1 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Trend1Cloud2 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Trend1Cloud3 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Trend1Cloud4 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
            )

        )
        (and
            (or
                (Cloud1 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Cloud2 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Cloud3 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
                (Cloud4 (cloudcount BKN|OVC))
            )
            (or
                (Trend1Cloud1 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
                (Trend1Cloud2 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
                (Trend1Cloud3 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
                (Trend1Cloud4 (cloudcount FEW|SCT))
            )

        )
)
)
=>
(asser 1))
```

here is my rule,the LHS contains two parts inside "or",each part loads well,but it will freezed the IDE when put the two parts together.but why?
my IDE is CLIPSIDE64,version 6.3

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in CLIPS. The permutations of the 'or' conditional elements in the rule generate 32 patterns of the following form:

(not (and (Cloud1 (cloudcount FEW | SCT)) 
          (Trend1Cloud1 (cloudcount BKN | OVC))))

Because of the bug, a long chain of these will take an inordinate amount of time to process. A fix has been been checked into the CLIPS SVN repository.

Regardless, I'd suggest parameterizing your facts if your requirements allow this:

```
(defrule example
   (not 
        (or 
            (and (Cloud (id 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) (cloudcount FEW | SCT))
                 (Trend (id 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) (cloudcount BKN | OVC)))

            (and (Cloud (id 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) (cloudcount BKN | OVC))
                 (Trend (id 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) (cloudcount FEW | SCT)))))
   =>)
```

Comment: thanks a lot.the problem is only appears in the IDE ,the rule runs fine int he DLL of . NET,did you fix it int the .NET DLL?by the way,what's the link of the CLIPS SVN repository?

Comment: The behavior is not specific to the Windows IDE. I get the same behavior in the Windows IDE and console applications as well as the OS X IDE and console applications. Which of the several .NET wrappers for CLIPS are you using?

Comment: the Mommosoft.ExpertSystem.dll,

Comment: The Mommosoft DLL is based on an older version of CLIPS. Either 6.2 or a beta version of 6.3